# Is it possible to get Country Name using Select Query in Magento 2 DB?

Tags: magento2, database, query, country-regions

I am trying to get the list of customers from the database directly using Mysql Query.

```
SELECT ce.email As Email, ce.firstname As Firstname, ce.lastname As Lastname,
COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.country_id,''), '') As Country, // here I want to show a country name like "united states", Right now it is returning country codes like "US", "Uk", etc..
COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.postcode,''), '') As Zip,
COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.telephone,''), '') As Phone
FROM customer_entity ce
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity cae 
ON ce.entity_id = cae.parent_id and ce.default_billing = cae.entity_id
```

**Right now, It is showing the below results and I have to show "United States" instead of "US", Is it possible to do that? as I did not find any entry for the country name on the database.**

| Email | Firstname | Lastname | Country | Zip | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test@test.com | firstname | lastname | US | 10001 | 7894561230 |

Answer (score 1):

Magento Doesn't Store Full Countries Name on the Database
It relies on a localization mechanism to display country names based on the locale or store view Using Zend Locale
Can be found on this path

./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/

In order to get full country name through SQL you will need to create a table that includes the country code and country name manually

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    country_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    country_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

then

```
INSERT INTO countries (country_code, country_name) VALUES
    ('001', 'World'),
    ('002', 'Africa'),
    ('003', 'North America'),
    ('005', 'South America'),
    ('009', 'Oceania'),
    ('011', 'Western Africa'),
    ('013', 'Central America'),
    ('014', 'Eastern Africa'),
    ('015', 'Northern Africa'),
    ('017', 'Middle Africa'),
    ('018', 'Southern Africa'),
    ('019', 'Americas'),
    ('021', 'Northern America'),
    ('029', 'Caribbean'),
    ('030', 'Eastern Asia'),
    ('034', 'Southern Asia'),
    ('035', 'South-Eastern Asia'),
    ('039', 'Southern Europe'),
    ('053', 'Australasia'),
    ('054', 'Melanesia'),
    ('057', 'Micronesian Region'),
    ('061', 'Polynesia'),
    ('142', 'Asia'),
    ('143', 'Central Asia'),
    ('145', 'Western Asia'),
    ('150', 'Europe'),
    ('151', 'Eastern Europe'),
    ('154', 'Northern Europe'),
    ('155', 'Western Europe'),
    ('419', 'Latin America'),
    ('AC', 'Ascension Island'),
    ('AD', 'Andorra'),
    ('AE', 'United Arab Emirates'),
    ('AF', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('AG', 'Antigua and Barbuda'),
    ('AI', 'Anguilla'),
    ('AL', 'Albania'),
    ('AM', 'Armenia'),
    ('AN', 'Netherlands Antilles'),
    ('AO', 'Angola'),
    ('AQ', 'Antarctica'),
    ('AR', 'Argentina'),
    ('AS', 'American Samoa'),
    ('AT', 'Austria'),
    ('AU', 'Australia'),
    ('AW', 'Aruba'),
    ('AX', 'Åland Islands'),
    ('AZ', 'Azerbaijan'),
    ('BA', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
    ('BB', 'Barbados'),
    ('BD', 'Bangladesh'),
    ('BE', 'Belgium'),
    ('BF', 'Burkina Faso'),
    ('BG', 'Bulgaria'),
    ('BH', 'Bahrain'),
    ('BI', 'Burundi'),
    ('BJ', 'Benin'),
    ('BL', 'Saint Barthélemy'),
    ('BM', 'Bermuda'),
    ('BN', 'Brunei'),
    ('BO', 'Bolivia'),
    ('BQ', 'Caribbean Netherlands'),
    ('BR', 'Brazil'),
    ('BS', 'Bahamas'),
    ('BT', 'Bhutan'),
    ('BV', 'Bouvet Island'),
    ('BW', 'Botswana'),
    ('BY', 'Belarus'),
    ('BZ', 'Belize'),
    ('CA', 'Canada'),
    ('CC', 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands'),
    ('CD', 'Congo - Kinshasa (DRC)'),
    ('CF', 'Central African Republic'),
    ('CG', 'Congo -  Brazzaville (Republic)'),
    ('CH', 'Switzerland'),
    ('CI', 'Ivory Coast - Côte d’Ivoire'),
    ('CK', 'Cook Islands'),
    ('CL', 'Chile'),
    ('CM', 'Cameroon'),
    ('CN', 'China'),
    ('CO', 'Colombia'),
    ('CP', 'Clipperton Island'),
    ('CR', 'Costa Rica'),
    ('CU', 'Cuba'),
    ('CV', 'Cape Verde'),
    ('CW', 'Curaçao'),
    ('CX', 'Christmas Island'),
    ('CY', 'Cyprus'),
    ('CZ', 'Czech Republic'),
    ('DE', 'Germany'),
    ('DG', 'Diego Garcia'),
    ('DJ', 'Djibouti'),
    ('DK', 'Denmark'),
    ('DM', 'Dominica'),
    ('DO', 'Dominican Republic'),
    ('DZ', 'Algeria'),
    ('EA', 'Ceuta and Melilla'),
    ('EC', 'Ecuador'),
    ('EE', 'Estonia'),
    ('EG', 'Egypt'),
    ('EH', 'Western Sahara'),
    ('ER', 'Eritrea'),
    ('ES', 'Spain'),
    ('ET', 'Ethiopia'),
    ('EU', 'European Union'),
    ('FI', 'Finland'),
    ('FJ', 'Fiji'),
    ('FK', 'Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)'),
    ('FM', 'Micronesia'),
    ('FO', 'Faroe Islands'),
    ('FR', 'France'),
    ('GA', 'Gabon'),
    ('GB', 'United Kingdom UK'),
    ('GD', 'Grenada'),
    ('GE', 'Georgia'),
    ('GF', 'French Guiana'),
    ('GG', 'Guernsey'),
    ('GH', 'Ghana'),
    ('GI', 'Gibraltar'),
    ('GL', 'Greenland'),
    ('GM', 'Gambia'),
    ('GN', 'Guinea'),
    ('GP', 'Guadeloupe'),
    ('GQ', 'Equatorial Guinea'),
    ('GR', 'Greece'),
    ('GS', 'South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands'),
    ('GT', 'Guatemala'),
    ('GU', 'Guam'),
    ('GW', 'Guinea-Bissau'),
    ('GY', 'Guyana'),
    ('HK', 'Hong Kong SAR China'),
    ('HM', 'Heard & McDonald Islands'),
    ('HN', 'Honduras'),
    ('HR', 'Croatia'),
    ('HT', 'Haiti'),
    ('HU', 'Hungary'),
    ('IC', 'Canary Islands'),
    ('ID', 'Indonesia'),
    ('IE', 'Ireland'),
    ('IL', 'Zionist entity'),
    ('IM', 'Isle of Man'),
    ('IN', 'India'),
    ('IO', 'British Indian Ocean Territory'),
    ('IQ', 'Iraq'),
    ('IR', 'Iran'),
    ('IS', 'Iceland'),
    ('IT', 'Italy'),
    ('JE', 'Jersey'),
    ('JM', 'Jamaica'),
    ('JO', 'Jordan'),
    ('JP', 'Japan'),
    ('KE', 'Kenya'),
    ('KG', 'Kyrgyzstan'),
    ('KH', 'Cambodia'),
    ('KI', 'Kiribati'),
    ('KM', 'Comoros'),
    ('KN', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'),
    ('KP', 'North Korea'),
    ('KR', 'South Korea'),
    ('KW', 'Kuwait'),
    ('KY', 'Cayman Islands'),
    ('KZ', 'Kazakhstan'),
    ('LA', 'Laos'),
    ('LB', 'Lebanon'),
    ('LC', 'Saint Lucia'),
    ('LI', 'Liechtenstein'),
    ('LK', 'Sri Lanka'),
    ('LR', 'Liberia'),
    ('LS', 'Lesotho'),
    ('LT', 'Lithuania'),
    ('LU', 'Luxembourg'),
    ('LV', 'Latvia'),
    ('LY', 'Libya'),
    ('MA', 'Morocco'),
    ('MC', 'Monaco'),
    ('MD', 'Moldova'),
    ('ME', 'Montenegro'),
    ('MF', 'Saint Martin'),
    ('MG', 'Madagascar'),
    ('MH', 'Marshall Islands'),
    ('MK', 'Macedonia (FYROM)'),
    ('ML', 'Mali'),
    ('MM', 'Myanmar (Burma)'),
    ('MN', 'Mongolia'),
    ('MO', 'Macau SAR China'),
    ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
    ('MQ', 'Martinique'),
    ('MR', 'Mauritania'),
    ('MS', 'Montserrat'),
    ('MT', 'Malta'),
    ('MU', 'Mauritius'),
    ('MV', 'Maldives'),
    ('MW', 'Malawi'),
    ('MX', 'Mexico'),
    ('MY', 'Malaysia'),
    ('MZ', 'Mozambique'),
    ('NA', 'Namibia'),
    ('NC', 'New Caledonia'),
    ('NE', 'Niger'),
    ('NF', 'Norfolk Island'),
    ('NG', 'Nigeria'),
    ('NI', 'Nicaragua'),
    ('NL', 'Netherlands'),
    ('NO', 'Norway'),
    ('NP', 'Nepal'),
    ('NR', 'Nauru'),
    ('NU', 'Niue'),
    ('NZ', 'New Zealand'),
    ('OM', 'Oman'),
    ('PA', 'Panama'),
    ('PE', 'Peru'),
    ('PF', 'French Polynesia'),
    ('PG', 'Papua New Guinea'),
    ('PH', 'Philippines'),
    ('PK', 'Pakistan'),
    ('PL', 'Poland'),
    ('PM', 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon'),
    ('PN', 'Pitcairn Islands'),
    ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
    ('PS', 'Palestine'),
    ('PT', 'Portugal'),
    ('PW', 'Palau'),
    ('PY', 'Paraguay'),
    ('QA', 'Qatar'),
    ('QO', 'Outlying Oceania'),
    ('RE', 'Réunion'),
    ('RO', 'Romania'),
    ('RS', 'Serbia'),
    ('RU', 'Russia'),
    ('RW', 'Rwanda'),
    ('SA', 'Saudi Arabia'),
    ('SB', 'Solomon Islands'),
    ('SC', 'Seychelles'),
    ('SD', 'Sudan'),
    ('SE', 'Sweden'),
    ('SG', 'Singapore'),
    ('SH', 'Saint Helena'),
    ('SI', 'Slovenia'),
    ('SJ', 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen'),
    ('SK', 'Slovakia'),
    ('SL', 'Sierra Leone'),
    ('SM', 'San Marino'),
    ('SN', 'Senegal'),
    ('SO', 'Somalia'),
    ('SR', 'Suriname'),
    ('SS', 'South Sudan'),
    ('ST', 'São Tomé and Príncipe'),
    ('SV', 'El Salvador'),
    ('SX', 'Sint Maarten'),
    ('SY', 'Syria'),
    ('SZ', 'Swaziland'),
    ('TA', 'Tristan da Cunha'),
    ('TC', 'Turks and Caicos Islands'),
    ('TD', 'Chad'),
    ('TF', 'French Southern Territories'),
    ('TG', 'Togo'),
    ('TH', 'Thailand'),
    ('TJ', 'Tajikistan'),
    ('TK', 'Tokelau'),
    ('TL', 'East Timor - Timor-Leste'),
    ('TM', 'Turkmenistan'),
    ('TN', 'Tunisia'),
    ('TO', 'Tonga'),
    ('TR', 'Turkey'),
    ('TT', 'Trinidad and Tobago'),
    ('TV', 'Tuvalu'),
    ('TW', 'Taiwan'),
    ('TZ', 'Tanzania'),
    ('UA', 'Ukraine'),
    ('UG', 'Uganda'),
    ('UM', 'U.S. Outlying Islands'),
    ('US', 'United States'),
    ('UY', 'Uruguay'),
    ('UZ', 'Uzbekistan'),
    ('VA', 'Vatican City'),
    ('VC', 'St. Vincent & Grenadines'),
    ('VE', 'Venezuela'),
    ('VG', 'British Virgin Islands'),
    ('VI', 'U.S. Virgin Islands'),
    ('VN', 'Vietnam'),
    ('VU', 'Vanuatu'),
    ('WF', 'Wallis and Futuna'),
    ('WS', 'Samoa'),
    ('XK', 'Kosovo'),
    ('YE', 'Yemen'),
    ('YT', 'Mayotte'),
    ('ZA', 'South Africa'),
    ('ZM', 'Zambia'),
    ('ZW', 'Zimbabwe'),
    ('ZZ', 'Unknown Region');
```

then you will be able to run the following query showing full country name successfully

```
SELECT 
    ce.email AS Email,
    ce.firstname AS Firstname,
    ce.lastname AS Lastname,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.country_id,''), '') AS Country_Code,
    COALESCE(c.country_name, '') AS Country,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.postcode,''), '') AS Zip,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(cae.telephone,''), '') AS Phone
FROM 
    customer_entity ce
LEFT JOIN 
    customer_address_entity cae ON ce.entity_id = cae.parent_id AND ce.default_billing = cae.entity_id
LEFT JOIN 
    countries c ON cae.country_id = c.country_code;
```